Having a hard time understanding an explanation about rate of convergence
I don't know if it's just me or the book but this one part stumps me.
In Linear and Nonlinear Optimization 2nd Edition by Nash & Sofer Chapter 2 Section 5 page 59 about Rate of Convergence, there's this following explanation of rate constant.

If $C > 1$, it says that the error sequence diverge, but isn't if the error sequence diverges then the original sequence diverges too and defeats the whole purpose of the definition where it should've been written from the start that we require $0<C<1$? Or is there something I'm missing here?
Note : $e_k = |x_k - x^*|$

Is $e_k= | x_k -x^*|$?

Yes. The error sequence is as usual
